# How to uninstall Edge extension?

Tags: microsoft-edge, browser-extension, appx

I install the extension (.appx), running in the context of the user, on first run of my separately installed Client, using:

```
Add-AppxPackage <PathToAppx>
```

I uninstall it as a custom action when the Client gets uninstalled, as administrator, using:

```
Remove-AppxPackage <PackageFullName> -AllUsers
```

The extension, when installed, shows up in *Add or Remove Programs* and in *Edge -> ... -> Extensions*.

After uninstallation, the extension gets removed from *Add or Remove Programs*, but it still shows as "enabled" in *Edge -> ... -> Extensions*, although the code and assets are gone - it no longer works. Machine restart does not fix it.

When I uninstall it manually - it is a separate app - from *Add or Remove Programs*, it behaves the same: does not get removed from *Edge*. [UPDATED]

How do I remove it from Edge? I'm guessing, I will need to modify some registry or file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following registry keys in HKEY_USERS need to be deleted for all users after removing the appx package:

```
\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\ExtensionsStore\datastore\Config\{PackageFamilyName}

\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\SystemAppData\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\PersistedStorageItemTable\ManagedByApp\{PackageFamilyName}
```

Notice that *PackageFamilyName* is used here, not *PackageFullName*.

Comment: From your last post, It looks like you had solved your issue. I suggest you to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question may help other community members in future in similar kind of questions. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Done. Thanks @Deepak-MSFT